# Varying the amplitude of a driven wave

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, power, resonance

I' d like to know whether varying the amplitude of a system at resonance is possible or not and if it is, how? I've calculated the resonance frequency of a material and I'd like to know the displacement this frequency generates and whether I can control it by knowing the relationship between the amplitude (displacement) at resonance and  power of driving source. It would make sense that increasing the power would increase the amplitude/displacement of the oscillation, but I need formulas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The amplitude at a resonance depends on damping friction and other energy dissipation mechanisms. Absent of those the amplitude is infinite.

You need to provide a better description of the system in order to derive the amplitude frequency relationships.